# Uniformity is generated by pseudometrics

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, uniform-spaces

How to prove that every uniform space is generated by a family of pseudometric spaces?

You may offer me a book. In Engelking this theorem is presented without a proof. In Willard it is a exercise. Can you propose me a book really having a proof of this theorem? Direct proof at MSE would be even better.

Comment: You need almost none of the exercise in Willard. All you need to do is verify that if $X$ is a uniform space, the collection of all pseudometrics produced by Lemma $38.1$ from uniform covers of $X$ generates the original uniformity which is itself a trivial consequence of $38.1$.

Answer (score 1):

From Bourbaki's *General topology. Chapters 5 to 10*, theorem 1 [page 142](http://books.google.com/books?id=bQwhdmL6IjUC&pg=PA142):

> **Theorem:** Given an uniformity $\mathcal{U}$ on a set $X$, there is a family of pseudometrics on $X$ such that the uniformity defined by this family is identical with $\mathcal{U}$.